# Where are objects stored in R packages?

Tags: r, package

I am refactoring an R package of another author (previous employee of my company). The author uses multiple variables in the `roxygen2` examples that apparently are stored somewhere in the package. They are accessible with `pkgname:::bar`. I renamed some of these variables across the entire package to improve naming consistency, let's say the variable is called `foo` instead of `bar` now, but the examples are not running any more upon `devtools::check()`. The error: `Error in get(name, envir = asNamespace(pkg), inherits = FALSE) : object 'foo' not found`. However, I cannot find where they are defined. There are no objects in the `data` folder that would be named `bar` and searching for the variable name within all files (in RStudio and in Windows Explorer) does not reveal anything. Yet, `pkgname:::bar` still works. Any ideas where I should look for `bar`?

Comment: What types of files are in the `data` folder? If they are `rdata` files they may contain multiple objects that wouldn't be obvious from the file names.

Comment: Yes, and the resulting confusion is precisely why having non-matching file and object names is considered bad practice (see `?data`). If that is the issue and you are refactoring the package, then you might consider reorganizing your `data`.

Comment: @GregorThomas Thanks for this hint. Even though in this particular case the objects were stored in `sysdata.rda`, it's good to know for the future where else I can look for objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables can also be created in a normal R script of the package with `foo <- new.env()` and then populated with content, e.g.

```r
foo <- new.env()

foo <- data.frame(
  x=1:10,
  y <- rnorm(10)
)
```

It is also possible to make the internal data hidden, e.g. `.foo`. As an example CRAN package marelac uses this mechanism in files `aaa.R`, `gas_schmidt.R` and some others.

Another possibility is a file `sysdata.rda` that can be placed in the `/R`folder, see: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Package-subdirectories